# RoboSpice ORMLite save a collection of objects

Tags: android, spring, ormlite, robospice

I'm using RoboSpice with Spring Android and I want to cache my requests to the local DB using ORMLite.
I'm performing a simple GET request to my server which returns a JSON Array of objects. I want these objects to be saved to the DB.
I tried using MyObject[] and ArrayList as the result of [SpringAndroidSpiceRequest](http://octo-online.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/request/springandroid/SpringAndroidSpiceRequest.html), but I get the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.mybusiness.MyObject$List is not handled by any registered factoryList
```

or

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.mybusiness.MyObject[] is not handled by any registered factoryList
```

I understand it doesn't recognize the collection because I passed MyObject.class to [InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory](http://octo-online.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/persistence/ormlite/InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory.html). 
But when I tried to add ClientBusiness[].class to the class collection passed to [InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory](http://octo-online.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/persistence/ormlite/InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory.html) I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class [Lcom.mybusiness.MyObject;
```

Any suggestions?

This is the code for MyObject:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "my_object")
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private long id;

    public long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(long id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code of MyObject.

Comment: @Snicolas I added the code for MyObject. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Clean everything and send a few more lines of stack traces. Everything looks good for my object and the error doesn't make much sense. Aslo don't use an array, use a list, and show how you add classes to the RoboSpiceDatabaseHelper.

Comment: @SoH Yes! But I don't have the code right now, I'll post an answer. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thanks @Benny. Will be waiting for it.

Comment: We still waiting for it)